# What is the URL to the Nokia Beamer web site?

Tags: untagged

I want to use Nokia Beamer on my TV but I have forgotten the address to the site which show the QR code. Do you know it?

Comment: Do you mean the URL that is shown right in the app when you launch it?

Comment: I know. Sometimes I launch the website before I launch the app. Maybe one day I'll google it.

Comment: Wish I could down vote my own question, haha.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is https://beam.nokia.com/.

Sadly beamer.nokia.com does not work.